# I'm struggling with clustering nifi for load balancing

Tags: cluster-computing, load-balancing, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I'm struggling with configuring NiFi load balancing cluster. I have three servers and i want to activate load balancing to share a high streaming dataflow between the three servers. I can't find a good documentation as to do that. Can someone share his experience on how to configure the files (nifi.properties , zookeeper.properties)??

Comment: Pierre Villard has written multiple blog posts about configuring clusters [Cluster Setup](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/), [Securing a cluster](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/29/apache-nifi-1-1-0-secured-cluster-setup/), and [Scaling up/down a cluster](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/30/scaling-updown-a-nifi-cluster/).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about load-balanced connections...

If you already have a working cluster, the only new properties for load-balancing are in nifi.properties:

```
# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=4
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec
```

If you have a secure cluster then you likely need to fill in the host to match the host in the certificate of each node, otherwise if you leave it blank then it binds to all interfaces.

Everything else related to load-balanced connections is done through the NiFi UI.

Comment: The problem is that i can't even create a cluster. Is there any tutorial to achieve that ? I'm new in the field of cluster computing.

Comment: Thank you for your support.